# Possible classification techniques to use when each feature is a probability distribution

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, classification, compositional-data

I am working with some data where the features have a *temporal* aspect (e.g. how often does a feature occur between $t_{begin}$ and $t_{end}$). I am trying to build a binary classifier for this data. The problem, however, is that each feature *is* a probability distribution. Normally, something like a SVM classifier would work: each object represented by a vector, where the $i^{th}$ index of the vector is a number (e.g. tf-idf, etc.).

I have no idea how to proceed where each object is represented by a set of probability distributions. The simple vector representation will clearly not be suitable. I've searched far and wide, but haven't found anything that suits this kind of data. Any pointers/ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Also, I wanted to add that I have looked into distances between distribution and density functions (e.g. [Wasserstein metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric), [Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_statistic) ), but I don't see how computing these metrics will help in the classification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use distribution-level metrics (such as the one you are mentioning), and calculate all dissimilarities between all samples. This will result in a dissimilarity matrix, which you can use as input for your classifier. In fact, this dissimilarity matrix can be used as a Kernel matrix, to which you could for example apply a Linear SVM.